# Problem starting Zabbix server

Tags: mysql, connection, zabbix

When trying to start the Zabbix server, I get the following error:

> Starting zabbix_server: /usr/local/sbin/zabbix_server [29360]: Cannot open [/tmp/zabbix_server.log] [Permission denied]
>                                                              [FAILED]

In My zabbix_server.log file:

> 18959:20100129:202911.592 [Z3001] Connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [104\
>   5] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

How do I change it so that it tries to connect with the correct user / password? (I have set a password for my root account, so it can't connect to the database.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, you have two mistakes here : 
The first one : the log have to be in /var/log (well or somewhere else but not into /tmp) :

edit the file /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf and look for this entry :

```
# Name of log file
# If not set, syslog is used

LogFile=/var/log/zabbix-server/zabbix_server.log
```

And check you have the same error. For the database access, you can launch :

```
dpkg-reconfigure zabbix-server
```

so you will be able to set a new password. OR, edit the file : 
/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf again, at the end of the file, you will see :

```
# Database user

DBUser=zabbix

# Database password
# Comment this line if no password used

DBPassword=foo

# Connect to MySQL using Unix socket?

#DBSocket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Note that you will also have to edit the file /etc/zabbix/dbconfig.php :

```
$DB["TYPE"]      = "mysql";
$DB["SERVER"]    = "localhost";
$DB["PORT"]      = "0";
$DB["DATABASE"]  = "zabbix";
$DB["USER"]      = "zabbix";
$DB["PASSWORD"]  = "foo";
$ZBX_SERVER      = "127.0.0.1";
$ZBX_SERVER_PORT = "10051";
```

so the password match.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Zabbix has a web interface to do the installation. Very neat. You may check [here](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/installation). It is better you read the entire installation procedure so that you do not end up in more errors.

Comment: But it doesn't have any option to configure the zabbix server itself...

Answer (score 0):

You'll better make a /var/log/zabbix directory whith appropriate permission and ownership and modify your zabbix_server.conf to write the log file here, by the way, assuming zabbix server has been compiled with mysql support, you need to create a mysql user for zabbix and grant him the needed privileges on the Zabbix database.

Here are are some links regarding setting up MySQL:

[Creating users in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-user.html)

[Assigning priliges in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/default/zabbix-server

set START=yes

Comment: I don't see how that will help with the problem that zabbix can't open its log file.